# Custom inputView breaks apart when UITextField is enabled in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am working on creating a custom keypad for my iPad app.  I created this keypad as a custom inputView and then assigning it to the inputView attribute for each textfield.  I built this keypad in storyboard, and when I place the cursor in any textfield, the delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{


    NSLog(@"how about here?");
    return YES;

}
```

gets called, but the keypad for some weird reason breaks up and is spread all over the screen.  I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is what the screen looks like when the app first loads:

[image: Before]

and here is how the app looks after I place the cursor in a textfield which calls the above method:

[image: After]

Here is what my screen looks like when I turn Autolayout off:

[image]

I honestly have no idea why this is happening.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: Autolayout? Try turning it off and see how that works out.

Comment: That actually helped alot!  However, my keypad still moves to the left on my screen (albeit fully intact this time which is a huge improvement).  Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Are you adding the number pad programmatically? can you post the code where you add it?

Comment: Well, if you added the custom num pad in IB, you will have to set the springs and struts manually in the Size Inspector to make sure that it doesn't move around when the interface changes. If you did it programmatically, then you will have to change the x,y coordinates to fix it in place. Either way should work.